# dbplyr::in_schema case sensitive

Tags: r, postgresql, dplyr, dbplyr

The function dbplyr::in_schema() can not connect to tables with uppercase letters.

When I create a table in PostgreSQL.

```
CREATE TABLE public."OCLOC"
(
  cod_ocloc double precision NOT NULL,
  lab_ocloc character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT pk_ocloc PRIMARY KEY (cod_ocloc)
);

INSERT INTO public."OCLOC"(
            cod_ocloc, lab_ocloc)
    VALUES (1, 'example');
```

Then I try to connect to the table using in_schema from R:

```
 con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL(), 
                  dbname = 'dbname', 
                  user = 'user', 
                  host = 'host', 
                  password = 'password')

 tbl(con, dbplyr::in_schema('public','OCLOC'))
```

Warns about the following error

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  no existe la relación «public.ocloc»
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM public.OCLOC AS "zzz3" WHERE 0=1
                  ^
)
```

But when I try without in_schema connection works:

```
tbl(con, 'OCLOC')
```

Looks like a case-insensitive problem, This generates a problem when I use database with other schemas besides the public and there are table names with capital letters.

Comment: I am not sure if the problem you are having is related to `in_schema`, as this seems to have no problem supporting capitalisation: `> dbplyr::in_schema('public','OCLOC')
<IDENT> public.OCLOC` Could the problem be with the driver instead? Did you try executing the produced query directly? `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, 'SELECT * FROM public.OCLOC AS "zzz3" WHERE 0=1')`

Comment: I also had issues with case sensitivity, connecting to Oracle. In the end I overwrote `DBI::dbWriteTable` and `DBI::dbReadTable` so they convert all queries and table names to uppercase before running. `dbplyr` is amazing but quite new and full of surprises, so I found (after half a day trying and not succeeding to rbind) it's safer to standardize (and minimize) the usage as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution as follows: adding `""` inside `''`

```
tbl(con, '"OCLOC"')
```